# find the sum of total items and price

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

im using jquery drag and drop for shopping cart , 
example link is http://jsfiddle.net/GPBUn/5/
i need to find the total products and sum of prices , any help

```
basket.find("ul").append('<li data-id="' + move.attr("data-id") + '">'                          
                            + '<span class="name">' + title + '</span>'
                            + '<span class="price">' + price + '</span>'
                            + '<input class="count" value="1" type="text" id="item' + ccounts + '">'
                            + '<input class="total" value="' + price + '" type="text" id="total' + ccounts + '">'
                            + '<button class="delete">&#10005;</button>');
                            ccounts++;
                            //  + '<button class="total">'+ (price)*($(".count").val())+'</button>'
                            var tott= tott+ $(this).parents('li').find('.total').html();
                        //  alert(tott);
```

Comment: ur drag is not working even

Answer (score 2):

There were few issues in terms of logic and in choosing proper selectors as well, so I have corrected them.

### Following are things which I have modified in your code

- Inside the `addBasket()` function you had used `.parents()` method, which was pointing to the root level of all the products , i.e, `ul` tag, hence always loading the first items details on any item being dropped. I changed this to `.closest()` as this would point to the exact root of the dropped product `<li>` tag.
- As of jQuery 1.7  `.live()` has been deprecated, so I have replaced that with `.on()` , which will work smoothly with delegated Events() . ref:https://api.jquery.com/on/
- Due to the use of `.live()` which won't work on elements which are generated dynamically, so the button `click` event to close the  product entries from basket and `focusout` event on the quantity field was not working, hence `.on` was used and even the selectors were changed.

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GPBUn/25/

Always go with the **KISS** principle: *Keep It Simple Silly*.